# Apache Spark ---- how spark reads large partitions from source when there is no enough memory

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose my data source contains data in 5 partitions each partition size is 10gb ,so total data size 50gb , my doubt here is ,when my spark cluster doesn't have 50gb of main memory how spark handles out of memory exceptions , and what is the best practice to avoid these scenarios in spark.

Answer (score 0):

50GB is data that can fit in memory and you probably don't need Spark for this kind of data - it would run slower than other solutions.

Also depending on the job and data format, a lot of times, not all the data needs to be read into memory (e.g. reading just needed columns from columnar storage format like parquet)

Generally speaking - when the data can't fit in memory Spark will write temporary files to disk. you may need to tune the job to more smaller partitions so each individual partition will fit in memory. see [Spark Memory Tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)

Arnon